# How to get windows login name

Tags: environment-variables, environment

How can I get windows login name?
I need to print to db 'machine name' ( ${__machineName} ) and 'user name'.
Is there a way to get current user name?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I found a way to do it.

I added JSR223 with the Java language and printed the following command:

```
log.info(System.getProperty("user.name"))
```